# I want a script which will take multiple column numbers from a user and reverse the contents

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want a Unix script which will take multiple column numbers from the user and reverse the contents.

```
declare -a param="$@"
# enter 0 when exit the insert element
echo "Enter the numbers"
read n
while [ $n -ne 0 ]
do
    x[$i]=`expr $n`
    read n
    let i++
done

#display the all array elements
echo "Array values ${x[@]}"
echo "Array values ${x[*]}"

# To find the array length
length=${#x[*]}
echo $length
```

Comment: Please include an example of your input data and desired output.

Answer (score 5):

A copy and paste of my answer to an extremely similar question on stack overflow, which was posted alongside an extremely similar answer to Gnouc's above...

```
_arr+=( '"${_arrev} is an actual "${array[@]}"' )
_arr+=( '"${_arrev} is created as a result"' )
_arr+=( '"of reversing the key order in"' )
_arr+=( '"this "${_arr}. It handles zsh and"' )
_arr+=( '"bash arrays intelligently by tracking"' )
_arr+=( '"shell "$ENV." quotes=fine ( i hope ) "' )

. <<REVERSE /dev/stdin                    ⏎
    _arrev=( $(: $((l=${#_arr[@]}${ZSH_VERSION++1})) ; printf '"${_arr[$(('$l'-%d))]}" ' `seq 1 $l`) )
REVERSE

echo ; printf %s\\n ${_arrev}

"shell "$ENV." quotes=fine ( i hope ) "
"bash arrays intelligently by tracking"
"this "${_arr}. It handles zsh and"
"of reversing the key order in"
"${_arrev} is created as a result"
"${_arrev} is an actual "${array[@]}"
```

This should handle any possible array, I think.

If you're interested in what's going on up there, I suggest you have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120528/how-to-define-similar-bash-function-at-once/120531#120531) first. Then maybe [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120475/how-can-i-pass-argument-stored-on-a-variable-to-wget/120487#120487), definitely [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119845/52934), and, if you've got the time, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120863/52934) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120736/parsing-process-command-line-arguments-from-pargs-in-a-shell-script/120817#120817).

In all of those answers I discuss different 
aspects of the here-document *(and in many others)* which you can use to your advantage. For instance I discuss twice-evaluating variables, which is done above, and in one declare a function that globally declares another function named *`"_$1"`* in just 5 or 6 lines - most of which were *`_$1() { func body ; }`.* It's pretty handy if you use it correctly.

Regarding the auto-switch between *`bash`/`zsh,`*  well that's something else, but very simple as well. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81457/trapping-errors-in-command-substitution-using-o-errtrace-ie-set-e/120008#120008).

So basically if you can create a *`bash`/`zsh,`* array you should be able to reverse it using only the 3 . <<...REVERSE lines. It does not need to loop over the array in the way a *`for loop`* does.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want to reverse contents of an array. You can do it with `for loop`:

```
for ((idx=${#x[@]}-1; idx >= 0; idx--))
do
  printf '%s ' "${x[idx]}"
done
```

Comment: This drops the last element in a zsh array.

Comment: @mikeserv: The script even doesn't work with `zsh`. I think OP only want `bash`.

Comment: In case someone wants to use the same couple of lines more than once.